# Script to write out stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am looking for a script that will write out all the sprocs in a SQL Server 2000 database to a textfile, preferably as a series of "CREATE PROCEDURE" statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise manager provides the ability to script any and all objects in the database. I'm using Sql 05, but I seem to remember the method being:

1. In the details/summary view, select all of the procedures that you want to script.
2. Right-click.
3. Select tasks-script... or whatever is similar.

Unfortunately I don't have SQL 2000 Enterprise Manager available in front of me, but there is an option in the context menu to script any objects you desire.